# Connection Error when trying to connect to Azure SQL Database from a Virtual Machine

Tags: azure-sql-database, connectivity

We're currently facing a connectivity issue while attempting to connect to the Azure database from our on-prem Virtual Machine (VM) through SQL Management Studio.Vm is hosted on ESXI. The VM consistently displays a network error message upon connection attempts. However, when we try the same connection from a physical server, it establishes successfully.

In addition, we've tested this connection from two other Virtual Machines, and unfortunately, they also encountered the same error.

Although we've ensured that Port 1433 is open on the VMs, we're perplexed as to why this issue persists exclusively within the VM environment despite our efforts.

please share your idea if you has similar connection problem in past

Comment: Hello, are you trying to connect to Azure SQL DB using its public endpoint, or private endpoint ?

Comment: also, is whole point to be able to access Azure SQL DB from SSMS? if yes, would installing SSMS on your local machine and connecting from there resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Let start by making sure you can connect using the current IP of your Azure SQL Database server. Let's ping the name of the Azure SQL server. The ping will fail but it should also return the current IP of the SQL Azure Server. You won't get that IP if DNS resolution is not working.

```
C:\>ping <myserver>.database.windows.net

Pinging data.sn1-1.database.windows.net [65.55.74.144] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Ping statistics for 65.55.74.144:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

Now try to [telnet](https://shellgeek.com/windows-install-telnet-client-using-powershell-cmd/) to port 1433 using the IP address returned.

```
C:\>telnet 65.55.74.144 1433

Connecting To 65.55.74.144...
```

If [Telnet](https://shellgeek.com/windows-install-telnet-client-using-powershell-cmd/) is successful, the window will change to a completely blank screen. Try connecting with that IP using SSMS again. If telnet is not successful, try tracert to identify at what step it fails to reach the Azure SQL Database server.

```
C:\>tracert 65.55.74.144

Tracing route to 65.55.74.144 over a maximum of 30 hops
1 2 ms 1 ms 1 ms 192.168.0.1
2 6 ms 5 ms 5 ms 10.33.34.50
3 5 ms 4 ms 5 ms 4-1-753.DLLSTX-LCR-07.verizon-gni.net [130.81.107.26]
4 8 ms 5 ms 5 ms so-6-2-0-0.DFW01-BB-RTR1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.28.208]
5 44 ms 43 ms 44 ms so-11-0-0-0.LCC1-RES-BB-RTR1-RE1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.17.40]
6 49 ms 44 ms 44 ms so-6-0-0-0.ASH-PEER-RTR1-re1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.10.90]
```